# How to access and read a property on an interface object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter

The method in code `section_1` is in the parent component and when I display the contents of the received event in `measurementCoordinates` in the browser's console I received:

```
onMeasurementCoordinatesReceived:-> [object Object]
```

But when I attempt to access any property of the received event I receive `undefined`.

Please let me know how to access and read a property on an interface object

**code**:

```
onMeasurementCoordinatesReceived(measurementCoordinates: ICoordinates) {
    console.log("onMeasurementCoordinatesReceived:-> " + measurementCoordinates);
}
```

**interface in the chils component**

```
export interface ICoordinates {
    originLng: number;
    originLat: number;
    destinationLng: number;
    destinationLat: number;
}
```

Comment: try logging like this `console.log("onMeasurementCoordinatesReceived:->", measurementCoordinates);` you will be able to expand the object and see what is inside in this case

Comment: You did not show what is emitted from child component. The interface is not an object, but a syntax what an object should have. For example, your ICoordinates interface will accept only 4 properties. If you try to add another property, say distance, while coding it will show you error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you can console.log a string + object with a "," instead of "+" like:
`console.log("string", object)`

otherwise, js will use the default toString "[object Object]"

you can access to a property like anyother object, just like:
`objectName.propertyName`